Package survival: testing survival differences at a certain time point using survdiff
I would like to test survival differences for a time point 5 years, while my dataset has a longer follow-up with some events occurring after this time point. I use survdiff to perform the log-rank testing. Can I specify the time point in the Surv function or do I need to build a new vector by replacing all data points exceeding 5 years? For the survfit object I can do this by requesting summary at a specific time point.
Thanks for your help.
surv.fit <- Surv(fu.times, dead)
fit.os <- survdiff(surv.fit ~ sex, data = x)
